# XSLT and PHP Views

Tags: php, templates, xslt

I just started playing around with XSLT and PHP. However what I can't figure out is, in normal template engine you would normally generate your HTML from at least two templates (the frame and the page content).
The "frame" would only contain the standard page layout

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Stylesheets etc would go here -->
    </head>
    <body>
    <!-- Content would go here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

while the content would contain the actual data.

What would be the best way to realize that using PHP and XSLT?

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like this:

View.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="layout.xsl"/>

    <xsl:template name="content">
        2. View Content
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="layout"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Layout.xsl

```
<xsl:template name="jscss"/>

<xsl:template name="layout">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>layout.xsl</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            1. Layout Content
            <xsl:call-template name="content" />
            3. Layout Content
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Transform View.xsl and you get:

```
1. Layout Content
2. View Content
3. Layout Content
```

Comment: I decided to go a similar way. Except I leave out all the "call-template" parts and just call apply-templates in layout.xsl ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are not using XSLT for what you should. XSLT transforms some data into something else. You might want to take a look at some [template engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29) like [PHP Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) before and clarify yourself about where each other stands on the technology stack.

Comment: you could use XSLT as a template engine. It may even be desirable, depending on what type of content you have. The journal http://JMIR.org uses XSLT to render HTML and PDF of articles from a standard XML format.